# How Can I design 2 rows navbar with Boostrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I created structure with paint. I need this with boostrap.
I tried so much but I am in confused..

How can I handle this easiest way?

The structure is in following image:
[image]

Thanks and Best Regards..